# Flutter - Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe error on Android

Tags: flutter

I'm getting an error for a Flutter project. I will start deactivating plugins one by one and hopefully find if one of them is causing the problem. Until then I'll leave this here in case anybody has suggestions.

`Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)`

`Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
E/GoogleMapController(29124): Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.3
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3
  provider: ^4.1.2
  google_sign_in: ^4.4.6
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.28
  latlong: ^0.6.1
  flappy_search_bar: ^1.7.2
  http: ^0.12.1
  image_cropper: ^1.2.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+4
  geolocator: ^5.3.1


Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-RO)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Opening the Android app with Android Studio showed the following notice:

```
Compilation is not supported for following modules: cloud_firestore, cloud_firestore_web, firebase_auth, 
firebase_core, firebase_auth_web, firebase_core_web, google_maps_flutter, flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle, 
google_sign_in, google_sign_in_web, 
location. 
Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.
```

Answer (score 13):

According to Flutter team's response, it's an Android protobuf issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27095#issuecomment-722857855.

It's been fixed in Android 11: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/art/+/1294616/.

Comment: is this warning harmful  for Android < 11 ?

Comment: @Alexa289 Don't think so.  Haven't found anyone mentioning anything harmful in related issues. By the way you can filter these logs in IDE: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27095#issuecomment-720425136

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by turning off the backup.
Add this tag on your file "android > app > src > debug > AndroidManifest.xml":

```
<application android:allowBackup="false">
```

Run

```
flutter clean
flutter run
flutter create .
```

Here is some information about your problem https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup .