# Flutter url_launcher: blank page when opening pdf

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Using latest version and failing for Android and iOS: `url_launcher: ^6.1.5`

```
<!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
```

...

```
    static openLink(String link) async {
// https://res.cloudinary.com/recipic/image/upload/v1663798152/odvxwkkztakrpd3gva1j.pdf
        final Uri url = Uri.parse(link);
        if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
          await launchUrl(url);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $link';
        }
      }
```

It just displays a blank page throwing no errors, just:

> Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add this in launchUrl() :

```dart
launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,);
```

and you might need to add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
```

then you should be able to open the PDF smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this link - [Flutter - Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61912481/flutter-accessing-hidden-method-lsun-misc-unsafe-error-on-android)

it give some insights

AND

I encourage you to add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` to avoid unforeseen error

```
<!--https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#check-browser-available-->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a web view for rendering PDFs instead of url_launcher: [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

Comment: this method was working in the past with same package